# Sparse matrices in SciPy defined by a function

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it possible to define a sparse matrix in scipy from a function rather than the laying out all the possible values? In the doc's I see that a sparse matrix can be created by

```
There are seven available sparse matrix types:
 csc_matrix: Compressed Sparse Column format
 csr_matrix: Compressed Sparse Row format
 bsr_matrix: Block Sparse Row format
 lil_matrix: List of Lists format
 dok_matrix: Dictionary of Keys format
 coo_matrix: COOrdinate format (aka IJV, triplet format)
 dia_matrix: DIAgonal format
```

All of these force you to specify the matrix beforehand, which takes up memory. Is there a way I can simply supply a function to calculate (i,j) when needed? The end goal is to calculate the few largest eigenvectors of the matrix through something like a Lanczos method.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid python loops?  Because (hopefully obviously) you can set the values after an empty sparse matrix is created:  `m[i,j] = fn(i,j)`

Comment: @Paul I'd ideally like to never set the values in memory - that is, I have a (very large) sparse matrix where the number of non-zero elements are greater than the size of my memory but are quick to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "no", but it's pretty easy i think to roll your own matrix-like object.  If you are using [`eigsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh) to get your answer, (which appears to be an implementation of the Lanczos algorithm.), then your matrix-like requires a [`matvec(x)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.matvec) method, which may or may not be easy.

I realize this is not a complete answer, but I hope this sets you on your way.

Comment: If the answer is a no - thats fine, I'll have to look around in a different library for what I need. Thanks!